# Credential error while fetching data from big query

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I am trying to fetch data from big query using python. Below is my code:

```
bg_client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json("soy-serenity.json")

QUERY = "(SELECT * from table_name)"

df = gbq.read_gbq(QUERY, project_id = 'soy-serenity', dialect = 'standard')
```

This was running till yesterday. Somehow its giving the below error:

```
read_gbq() got an unexpected keyword argument 'credentials'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```py
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import pandas_gbq

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'soy-serenity.json',
)
sql = "SELECT * from table_name"
df = pandas_gbq.read_gbq(sql, project_id="soy-serenity", credentials=credentials)
```

Comment: what are you imports?

Answer (score 0):

The [following link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library) shows an example that you can run to fetch data from BigQuery using Python :

```
import os
from google.cloud import bigquery

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'path_to_soy-serenity.json'
client = bigquery.Client()

query = ("SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`")
query_job = client.query(query, location="US",) 

for row in query_job:  # API request - fetches results
    assert row[0] == row.name == row["name"]
    print(row)
```